# UIView animation while scrolling a table

Tags: uitableview, animation, uiview, scroll

I have a `UITableView` in an iPad, and its right half side is covered with a view.

What I want is: when the user scroll the `UITableView`, I want the covering view to slide (with an animation) to the right until its `origin.x` is at the end of the right side of the table, so the `UITableView` is clear to see (just like in the Twitter app for iPad).

The problem is: You can scroll the `UITableView` and animate a view at the same time. When I start scrolling, I use `didStartDraging` and even DidScroll to create a `[UIView animate...]` method, but this method stuck my scrolling.

I tired with block animation. I tried with Gestures. I tried with `CABasicAnimation`, and it goes quite OK, but somehow all the `UISubview` "Touch area" in my sliding view stay at the old place (what I mean is that the view gets its new frame, but I can scroll a `UIScrollView`, which is a `UISubview` of my view, even when my finger is out of the superviews frame S-:, even that there is no view at that point on screen.)

Any thoughts how can I make the animation without damaging the scroll of the table? (and I heard about the timer in the K and the `runloop` common modes. Not so helping)

Thanks.

Comment: Everything works fine for me with [UIView animate...] in scrollViewDidScroll:

Answer (score 0):

scrollview Delegate methods will be invoked for tableView also ............

you can use following code it worked for me and hope will work for you also.......

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(50, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    }];

}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(100, scrollView.frame.origin.y, scrollView.frame.size.width, scrollView.frame.size.height)];
    }];

}
```

set x position of scrollView(tableView) as your requirement......

Have a happy coding....